# PDO exception is not being thrown

Tags: php, pdo

I am new to PDO and a few things about it confuse me, I've tried creating a test function to see whether an exception will be thrown for an invalid query but nothing is thrown.

here is the code

```
<?php
include_once("/var/www/include/constants.php");

class DB{
    private $DBH; 

    public function DB(){
        try{
            $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_SERVER.";dbname=".DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);   
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {  
            echo $e->getMessage(); 
        }
    }

    public function test(){
        try{
            $DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );  
            $DBH->prepare('DELECT id FROM users');  
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {  
            echo $e->getMessage();  

        }
    }

};

/* Create database connection */
$db = new DB;
$db->test();

?>
```

Comment: @feeela it should be SELECT not DELECT

Comment: A `select id from users` is not invalid?

Comment: @JvdBerg I don't understand what you mean, the query `DELECT id FROM users` is invalid

Comment: mk_89 that's his point, he's trying to test throwing exceptions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Besides the missing references to the `$this` of your database handle, your need to tell PDO that it must not emulate prepares. The code below **will** throw a exception like this:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELECT id FROM
>   users' at line 1

```
class DB{
    private $DBH; 

    public function DB(){
        try{
            $this->DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=movies", 'root', 'jsat12');   
            $this->DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false );
      }
        catch(PDOException $e) {  
            echo $e->getMessage(); 
        }
    }

    public function test(){
        try{
            $this->DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );  
            $this->DBH->prepare('DELECT id FROM users');  
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {  
            echo $e->getMessage();  

        }
    }

};

/* Create database connection */
$db = new DB;
$db->test();
```

Comment: This finally threw an exception

Comment: Is there any way to cause an error when emulate prepares is enabled?

Answer (score 0):

There is no exception because you're not producing one. I guess you should see warning, error or something saying variable is not defined. Check your error reporting settings.

In `test`, you use `$DBH`, but it does not exist on local stack, but as an object member. Therefore, you should use `$this->DBH = new PDO(..)` to assign a value to an object member in constructor method, and `$this->DBH->setAttribute(...)` in `test` method to use it.

Here you go, corrected version:

```
<?php
include_once("/var/www/include/constants.php");

class DB{
    private $DBH; 

    public function DB(){
        try{
            $this->DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_SERVER.";dbname=".DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);   
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {  
            echo $e->getMessage(); 
        }
    }

    public function test(){
        try{
            $this->DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );  
            $this->DBH->prepare('DELECT id FROM users');  
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {  
            echo $e->getMessage();  

        }
    }

};

/* Create database connection */
$db = new DB;
$db->test();
```

Comment: I gave this a shot and nothing is returned.

Comment: well that is probably because you've got no exception. Try some nonsense query, like $this->DBH->prepare('foo bar')