# Why are setAttribute() functions causing invalid parameter error?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I am querying a database using mysql with a simple select statement. I am using one named parameter using a PDO prepared statement, but I am getting the HY093 error that I am using an invalid number of parameters, which doesn't make much sense to me, since I only have one parameter.

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME . ';charset=UTF8', DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

    // These variables let mysql errors throw PDO Exceptions. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12872698/83916 and http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2011/handling-sql-errors-in-pdo
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
    $dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
    $dbh->setAttribute( \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false );
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    die('pdo connection error: ' . $e->getMessage());
}

$hotel_slug = "sh";
$sql = "select count(*) as count from hotel h where h.hotel_slug = :hotel_slug";
$sql_param[':hotel_slug'] = $hotel_slug;

$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);

if(!$sth->execute($sql_param)){
    echo "<h2>An error has occurred</h2><br />";
    $error_array = $sth->errorInfo();
    var_dump($error_array);
} else {
    $result_count = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $row = current($result_count);
    $count = $row['count'];

    echo "Count: $count<br />";
}
```

This is what is appearing on the page:

**AN ERROR HAS OCCURRED**

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'HY093' (length=5)
  1 => null
  2 => null
```

I realized that the error is occurring because of the last two setAttribute() functions I am using after I open the database connection. I have included those, so I can throw Mysql exceptions on try/catch blocks throughout the site if a mysql error occurs, so I can use that exception data to email myself error reports when a user experiences a mysql error, since mysql errors do not throw exceptions by default.

Why are those functions causing errors on this page and how can I still use them without issues here?

Comment: `h.hotel_slug = ':hotel_slug'` remove the quotes. It's a bind and not a string value. Plus, read the manual http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: I have made the necessary correction, but I still get the error. Doesn't change anything.

Comment: Get rid of ERRMODE_WARNING. Only use ERRMODE_EXCEPTION. Your code looks like it should work, though since you're catching exceptions you don't need the `if()` surrounding the `execute()` call. Just do `$sth->execute()` followed by the `fetchAll()` code and catch any error it throws.

Comment: You need to change either:  _`PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false`_ to: _`PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true`_ . Or: Keep your current settings and change: _`:hotel_slug` to: _`?`_. What you have conflicts with the 'native mysql driver' you are using: [Use this setting to force PDO to either always emulate prepared statements (if TRUE), or to try to use native prepared statements (if FALSE).](https://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php)