# PHP PDO Exceptions

Tags: php, mysql, exception, pdo, transactions

I have a problem which I couldn't solve for a long time. I have a simple DB class like this one

```
class DB {

    private static $dbserver = "mysql:dbname=db;host=localhost";
    private static $dbuser = "root";
    private static $dbpass = "";

    public static function connectDB() {

        @$dbh = new PDO(self::$dbserver, self::$dbuser, self::$dbpass);
        $dbh->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, 'SET NAMES utf8');

        return $dbh;
    }
```

And a Service Class with methods to write data in the DB. The type of the tables is InnoDB. The Service Class looks like this

```
function insert_data($data) {
    $error = NULL;
    try {
        $dbh = DB::connectDB();
        $dbh->beginTransaction();

        $query_insert_1 = 'INSERT INTO table (f1, f2, f3) VALUES (?,?,?)';
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query_insert_1);
        $stmt->execute(array($d1, $d2, $d3));

        $last_insert_id = $dbh->lastInsertId();

        $query_insert_2 = 'INSERT INTO table2 (f4, f5, f6) VALUES (?,?,?)';
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query_insert_2);
        $stmt->execute(array($last_insert_id, $d4, $d5));

        $dbh->commit();             
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {                       
        $dbh->rollback();
        $error = $e->getMessage();
    }
    $return = new Result($error ? 1 : 0, $error ? 0 : 1, $error ? $error : '', NULL);
    error_log(print_r($error,1));
    return $return;
}
```

PDO only throws an Exception if I set PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE to PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION IN the function insert_data. If I set it in the DB class no Exception will be thrown. What is the reason for this behaviour?

I have the solution to throw an Exception when I set the constant in the function from this question ([PDO exception is not being thrown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12872601/pdo-exception-is-not-being-thrown))

Thanks for help

Michael

EDIT:
My originally code is the following

```
class CarService {

private $dbh;

function __construct($dbh) {
    $this->dbh = $dbh;
}

function insert_car($customer_id, $brand, $model) {
    $error = NULL;

    try {
        $this->dbh->beginTransaction();

        $query_insert_car = 'INSERT INTO fahrzeug (kunde_id, fabrikat, modell) VALUES (?,?,?)';

        $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query_insert_car);
        $stmt->execute(array($customer_id, $brand, $model));
        // Get the ID of the last inserted car
        $last_insert_id = $this->dbh->lastInsertId();
        // Create the entry of the corresponding car version
        $query_insert_car_version = 'INSERT INTO fahrzeugversion (fahrzeug_id, version, fabrikat, modell) VALUES (?,?,?,?)';
        $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query_insert_car_version);
        $stmt->execute(array($last_insert_id, 1, $brand, $model));

        $this->dbh->commit();               
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {                       
        $this->dbh->rollback();
        $error = $e->getMessage();
    }

    $return = new Result(1, 0, NULL, NULL);
error_log(print_r($error,1));
    return $return;
}
```

new_car.php

```
<?php

require_once('DB.php');
require_once('CarService.php');
require_once('Result.php');

$dbh = DB::connectDB();
$car_service = new CarService($dbh);

$result = new Result(1, 0, NULL, NULL);

if (isset($_POST['fabrikat']) && isset($_POST['modell'])) {
    $brand = trim($_POST['fabrikat']);
    $model = trim($_POST['modell']);

    $result = $car_service->insert_car(1, $brand, $model);          
}   
print_r(json_encode($result));
?>
```

DB.php

```
<?php

class DB {

    private static $dbserver = "mysql:dbname=db;host=localhost";
    private static $dbuser = "root";
    private static $dbpass = "";

    public static function connectDB() {

        $dbh = new PDO(self::$dbserver, self::$dbuser, self::$dbpass);
        $dbh->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, 'SET NAMES utf8');
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        return $dbh;
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Just a guess, but try taking the @ off your $dbh assignment. It suppresses error messages.

Comment: Hello, I think it's not the problem. If I make an error in the MySQL-syntax such as a wrong field name no exception will be thrown if I set the ERR_MODE in the DB class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` attribute to the PDO connection process

```
public static function connectDB() {

    $dbh = new PDO(self::$dbserver, self::$dbuser, self::$dbpass);
    $dbh->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    $dbh->setAttribute(\PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, 'SET NAMES utf8');
    $dbh->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    return $dbh;
}
```

and it will be set for everything that uses this connection until you close it.

now you can remove it from anywhere else that you were setting it

> NOTE:
>
> Maybe this is just a misunderstanding about when the exception will be thrown.
>
> When PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE is set to PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION exceptions will be thrown.
>
> BUT:
>
> If `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES = fale` the `->prepare()` statement issues the query to the database for compilation, therefore you will get the exception thrown by the `->prepare()` if the query does not compile.
>
> Now if `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES = true` the prepare statement does very little. The query is not issued to the database for compilation at this point. The query will be issued to the database for compilation as part of the `->execute()` processing and any execptions thrown relating to failed compilation will be thrown by the `->execute() statement.

Comment: Hello RiggsFolly, when I do this no exception will be thrown. This was my default setting. Since I add the PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION attribute in the try-block an exceptions will be thrown.

Comment: Then something else is wrong as well. Let me look closer

Comment: Hmmm actually this is not a good process. Your code will require you to make a connection in every method and you only want to make a connection once per script

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've solved the problem. I think it was a problem with my XAMPP. I've deinstalled and installed it and now it works :-)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some of your other code is setting PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION to another value.

If you bother to write an *isolated* working example involving **only** the code you posted here, you will see that exception will be thrown all right.